# Grep ticket number from text perl

Tags: regex, perl, grep, numbers

I need to grep the following:
`my $string = "Thanks for contacting support. Your ticket number: 123. All the best!"`
or
`my $string = "Thanks for contacting support. Your ticket #: 123. All the best!`"

How can I grep `123` into variable `$ticket_no` with PERL?

I think the regexp should be something like this  `ticket[ \t]+(number|#)?[: \t]+([0-9]+)`

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that regex would work. You could use it like this:

```
$string =~ m/ticket[ \t]+(number|#)?[: \t]+([0-9]+)/;
my $ticket_no = $2;
```

Note that you'll want to handle, somehow, the case that the regular expression *didn't* match, since in that case, `$ticket_no` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As ruakh already said - your regex would work.

As a hint: There are tons of regex test sites out there that make the testing and optimizations of regular expressions easy.

An example would be: http://myregextester.com/